# Lost access to Gmail

Tags: gmail, two-factor-authentication, google-accounts

Here is my situation:

- Lost SMS service through carrier
- Reset phone, so lost OTP app
- Do not have backup codes
- No other backup phone on account
- Now I cannot access any of my Gmail accounts

I cannot reset password because I cannot receive SMS.
I cannot re-setup OTP because I cannot access my account.

I have submitted the account recovery form 4 times now but keep getting rejected.  The thing is I honestly don't remember the exact dates I opened my accounts.  Other than that I don't know why it keeps getting rejected.

Is there ANY way for me to recover my account?

Comment: Contact someone that works at Google, best is to ask in the Google forums because there are people who work for Google there.

Comment: We can't help there is no other way to recover Google Account you really should have backed up the codes

Comment: What are backup codes? How do I set them? Do you mean passwords?